# "error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal"

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a JavaScript code of photo gallery with a slider but there's a problem :

```
 var partnum = "<%Response.Write(Request.QueryString["partno"]); %>";

    // check if the file is exiset -- it's running in bar() function -- run on servers and local host. 
    function UrlExists(url) {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('GET', url, false);
        http.send();
        return http.status != 404;
    }

    // push images paths to array 
    function bar() {
        var exict = 0;
        var counter = 0; //counter of array's index
        for (var i = 1 ; exict < 30; i++) {
            // if there isn't .jpg or .gif
            if (!UrlExists("/assets/catalog/parts/" + partnum + "_" + i + ".jpg") && !UrlExists("/assets/catalog/parts/" + partnum + "_" + i + ".gif")) {
                exict = exict + 1;
            }
            // if there is .jpg
            if (UrlExists("/assets/catalog/parts/" + partnum + "_" + i + ".jpg") && !UrlExists("/assets/catalog/parts/" + partnum + "_" + i + ".gif")) {
                arrOfImgs.push("/assets/catalog/parts/" + partnum + "_" + i + ".jpg");
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
            // if there is .gif 
            if (UrlExists("/assets/catalog/parts/" + partnum + "_" + i + ".gif") && !UrlExists("/assets/catalog/parts/" + partnum + "_" + i + ".jpg")) {
                arrOfImgs.push("/assets/catalog/parts/" + partnum + "_" + i + ".gif");
                gifIndex.push(i);
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        }
}
```

but it was not work, so i tried to change var partnum 
 `var partnum = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Request.QueryString['partno']) %>;`

but I got error: "error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal". I'm still not sure that this is the issue, as my original code does work (you can see the initial product image loaded when you visit the site [.baumhaus](http://www.baumhaus.co.uk/default.aspx?serverid=NewBaum) and click on a product range and then any product, you will see the action  - before it disappears once it tries to render the thumbnails).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var partnum = '<%= Request.QueryString["partno"] %>'";
```